# How to set a list to remove duplicates and to show only last entry by date?

Tags: c#, listbox, duplicates

I have created a program which collects:

- HWID
- public IP Address
- Date and time when program is launched

Program is designed to append those values, each in "Environment.NewLine" and result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Next step was to separate those entries, so I can have them in 3 different listBoxes and here is the class code I used :

```
public DB_List(string fajl) //Fajl u Listu pretvaranje
{
    newFajl = fajl;
}
public Tuple < List < string > , List < string > , List < string >> ListSeparator()
{
    string[] FajlA = File.ReadAllLines(newFajl);
    List < string > one = new List < string > ();
    List < string > two = new List < string > ();
    List < string > three = new List < string > ();
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < FajlA.Length; i += 3)
        {
            one.Add(FajlA[i]);
            two.Add(FajlA[i + 1]);
            three.Add(FajlA[i + 2]);
        }
    }
    return Tuple.Create(one, two, three);
}
```

Code in main Form :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = (@"data\blabl.txt");
    DB_List liste = new DB_List(a);
    var Lista = liste.ListSeparator();
    listBox1.DataSource = Lista.Item1; // HWID
    listBox2.DataSource = Lista.Item2; // cpuIP
    listBox3.DataSource = Lista.Item3; // cpuTime
}
```

The result is this : [image: 3 Listboxes]

Final :
In the screenshot I've selected what I would like to be displayed.
Basically, I would like:

- duplicates to be removed from ListBox1 and ListBox2 ( latest entry to be displayed )
- In ListBox3 - only latest date to be displayed according to the index of  listBox1.DataSource and listBox2.DataSource

Comment: For one and two don't use List, but use HashSet. For three, just sort it, and take the latest time.

Answer (score 1):

You want your lists to show only changes, right? 
then your data structure is wrong.

It has to be something like

```
public List<Tuple<string,string, string>> ListSeparator()
        {
            string[] FajlA = File.ReadAllLines(newFajl);
            var results =new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();


                for (int i = 0; i < FajlA.Length; i += 3)
                {
                    results.add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(FajlA[i], FajlA[i + 1], FajlA[i + 2]);
             }


            return results;
        }
```

Then on your load you can get distinct data and use them like this:

```
string a = (@"data\blabl.txt");
    DB_List liste = new DB_List(a);
    var Lista = liste.ListSeparator().Distinct();
    listBox1.DataSource = Lista.Select(l => l.item1).tolist ; // HWID
```

Comment: Great way of thinking, but I got this error : http://prntscr.com/bw3n04 and http://prntscr.com/bw3n6v

Comment: @qretsar on first one, I've forgotten the "new" keyword, and second one Select is the correct typing.
also dont forget to use System.Linq

Comment: I think that final result would be : http://prntscr.com/bw456l and I managed it how do it at first place, but the time is making a problem. It is always different.
 P.S. Again I'm receiving an error in your code. This time : http://prntscr.com/bw46gm